# Nested ASP.NET tabs

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I am trying to get a control tab inside another using ASP.NET and Ajax control toolkit , this is the code which i am using:

```
 <asp:TabContainer ID="TabContainer1" runat="server" ActiveTabIndex="0">
     <asp:TabPanel runat="server" HeaderText="Main tab" ID="TabPanel1">
        <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:TabPanel HeaderText="Nested tab" ID="TabPanel2" runat="server">
                        <ContentTemplate>
                            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Delete" />
                        </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:TabPanel>            
        </ContentTemplate>
      </asp:TabPanel>
    </asp:TabContainer>
```

but i am getting an exception saying that :

> "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

I do not know what to do here, because my design needs to have a tab panel inside another one, is this possible ?

Comment: The exception must be coming from the code behind. Can we see the code which throws the exception?

Comment: Hi, thank you for posting, the code behind is empty... only the page load event is there but has no implementation.  The code which throws this exception comes from AjaxControToolkit, saying this : "> AjaxControlToolkit.DLL!AjaxControlToolkit.TabPanel.OnInit(System.EventArgs e = {System.EventArgs})" and than the above exception occurs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The nested `<asp:TabPanel>` should be in its own `<asp:TabContainer>`, that is probably what the exception is about: the object reference is probably the container, and it is not set to an instance since it's missing for the nested tab.

```
<asp:TabContainer ID="TabContainer1" runat="server" ActiveTabIndex="0">
  <asp:TabPanel runat="server" HeaderText="Main tab" ID="TabPanel1">
    <ContentTemplate>

      <%-- You need another container before you can add a nested tab --%>
      <asp:TabContainer ID="NestedContainer1" runat="server">
        <asp:TabPanel HeaderText="Nested tab" ID="TabPanel2" runat="server">
          <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Delete" />
          </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:TabPanel>
      </asp:TabContainer>
      <%-- End of the second container --%>

    </ContentTemplate>
  </asp:TabPanel>
</asp:TabContainer>
```